# How do I feed a quoted argument to perl in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to call a perl script from powershell where a parameter is quoted:

```
myProg -root="my path with spaces"
```

I've tried to use `-root='"my path with spaces"'`, `-root='my path with spaces'`, `-root=\"my path with spaces\"`, but nothing seems to work. After pressing `<ENTER>`, I see `>>` as a prompt.

How do I pass this quoted argument on the command line in Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the entire argument in quotes and escape the inner quotes, that way powershell won't try to parse it:

```
myProg '-root=\"my path with spaces\"'
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to explicitly denote each command-line argument. Instead of relying on the parser to figure out what the arguments are via whitespace, you explicitly create an array of strings, one item for each command-line argument.

```
$cmdArgs = @( `
    '-root="my path with spaces"', `
    'etc', `
    'etc')

& "C:\etc\myprog.exe" $cmdArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue with

```
Invoke-Expression '&.\myProg.exe `-u:IMP `-p: `-s:"my path with spaces"'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to use powershell to pass arguments with spaces to an executable. In the end I found that I could get a quoted parameter passed by triple-escaping the **closing** double quote of the argument when using Invoke-Expression:

````
iex "&`"C:\Program Files\Vendor\program.exe`" -i -pkg=`"Super Upgrade```" -usr=User -pwd=password2"
````

What isn't apparent is why I can use a single back-tick character to escape the executable while I have to use 3 back-ticks to finish off a quoted parameter. All I know is that this is the only solution that worked for me.